# in texas holdem player x has q2 and player L has q10 and you have in the flop qqjA who wins

Tags: texas-hold-em

in texas holdem player x has q2 and player L has q10 and you have in the flop qqjA who wins

Comment: It is a split pot. The best five card hand for both players is QQQAJ. You only gave a four card board here.

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear.

we are on turn ??  The board is Q Q J A ??

what are the suits of the cards??

In any case in texas holdem the best 5 card combination wins (with or without one or two of your cards).

In this example :

if river is a K , player L win with straight;

if River is a J , split pot with full house;

if river is a T , win player L with a full house;

river 9 to 3, split pot; (with a set of Q, with A and J -> QQQAJ)

if river is a 2, win player X with a full house;

if river is a A, split pot.

Search more on best point in texas holdem and example ;)